# Connecting to remote server ps.outlook.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using below code to connect to exchange online for querying mailbox from .net application. It is working fine in development server but failed on production server. There is no issue with service account as I am able to connect to exchange online using `PowerShell` script.

```
var varSecurePwd = new SecureString(); 
try 
{ 
   foreach (var c in strAccountPwd)
   { 
      varSecurePwd.AppendChar(c); 
   } 

   PSCredential psCreds = new PSCredential(strAccountName, varSecurePwd); 
   psConnInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(strExchange2010PSURI), "Microsoft.Exchange", psCreds);

   psConnInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
   psRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(psConnInfo);
   psRunSpace.Open();
   psPipeLine = psRunSpace.CreatePipeline(); 
}
```

> Error:Connecting to remote server ps.outlook.com failed with the
>   following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see
>   the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

*Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*

*Exception Details: System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException: Connecting to remote server ps.outlook.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.*

Comment: var varSecurePwd = new SecureString();
    try
    {
        foreach (var c in strAccountPwd)
        {
            varSecurePwd.AppendChar(c);
        }
        PSCredential psCreds = new PSCredential(strAccountName, varSecurePwd);
        psConnInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(strExchange2010PSURI), "Microsoft.Exchange", psCreds);
        psConnInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
        psRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(psConnInfo);

        psRunSpace.Open();
        psPipeLine = psRunSpace.CreatePipeline();

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the code to your question. Read [the help topic on formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for how to make it look like code.

Answer (score 0):

It might have MFA enabled for service account hence it is failing for this command.